# JQuery Smooth Scroll to Anchor with Sticky Navigation Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a webpage with a sticky header that I'm attempting to implement smooth scrolling to anchor tags for navigation. When I click on the navigation link to the section I want to go `scrollTop: href.offset().top - 100` does not appear to work correctly. If I click the link again after the webpage has navigated to that section, I can see the page scroll, but then it bounces back to the top. Any idea what is going on? I'm using Microsoft Edge (Yeah, I know ...).

> HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body id="home">
    <nav><a href="#section1">Section #1</a></nav>
    <main>
        <!-- INSERT A BUNCH OF <BR> TAGS -->
        <h2 id="section1">section1</h2>
        <!-- INSERT A BUNCH OF <BR> TAGS -->
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

> CSS

```
nav {
    position:fixed;
    padding:4px;
border:2px solid #000;
width:100%;
    line-height:2.25em;
    background-color:yellow;
}

h2 {
    padding:4px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:100%;
    line-height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    }
```

> jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a[href*="#"]').click(function(event) {

        var href = $(this.hash);

        if (href.length) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: href.offset().top - 100
            }, 750, function() {
                location.hash = href.attr('id');
            });     
        }
    });
});
```

> [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ky4La0s1/41/)

EDIT:

I understand that setting a `<div>` element to `display:fixed` removes it from the flow of the page, which is what I believe is causing the issues. Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was suggested before, Microsoft Edge does not appear to properly support the .hash feature without causing some ill effects such as the rebounding of the smooth scroll feature. In order to work around this, I decided to use `pushState` for browsers that supported it, which achieved the desired effect.

> HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body id="home">
    <nav><a href="#section1">Section #1</a></nav>
    <main>
        <!-- INSERT A BUNCH OF <BR> TAGS -->
        <h2 id="section1">section1</h2>
        <!-- INSERT A BUNCH OF <BR> TAGS -->
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

> CSS

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 2.25em;
    background-color: yellow;
}

h2 {
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

> JAVASCRIPT

```
$('a[href*="#"]').click(function(event) {

    var href = $(this.hash);

    if (href.length) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: href.offset().top - 100
        }, 750, function() {
            if (history.pushState) {
                history.pushState(null, null, 'index.html#' + href.attr('id'));
            } else {
                location.hash = href.attr('id');
            }
        });     
    }
});
```

I was not able to figure out how to dynamically pull the calling file name, for example index.html or main.html to dynamically generate the hashed URL so that will have to be updated per page. Otherwise, this works exactly how I had expected. Please see the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ky4La0s1/65/) implementation for a working example.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT:

Edge and Firefox were not cooperating with initial approach to modify `hashchange` behavior, so this edit simply removes the `window.location.hash` step to prevent the jump after the animation. However, this is not ideal because it prevents the default hash location behavior.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]').on('click', (event) => {
    const hash = event.currentTarget.hash;
    if (hash) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 100}, 750);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 2.25em;
  background-color: yellow;
}

h2 {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body id="home">
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav><a href="#section1">Section #1</a></nav>
    <!-- Main Content -->
    <main>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <h2 id="section1">section1</h2>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

ORIGINAL:

I think `location.hash` causes the scroll to jump to the top after the `scrollTop` animation has completed. You can modify the `hashchange` event to stop the scroll at the same distance above your anchors to eliminate the jump.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - 100);
  });
  
  $('a[href*="#"]').on('click', (event) => {
    const hash = event.currentTarget.hash;
    if (hash) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 100
      }, 750, function() {
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This does not appear to work. JSFiddle and the `Run code snippet` didn't produce the desired results. Subsequent clicks on the navigation resulted in the same behavior as before.

Comment: @AaronTomason sure enough, I see what you mean in Edge (also happens in Firefox). Currently this approach is only working in Chrome (will look into it a bit more).

Comment: @AaronTomason edited answer for a solution that I think achieves what you are after visually across browsers but unfortunately does not actually set `window.location.hash` (which is less than ideal).

Comment: thanks for the update. I was hoping to keep the hash so I could retain the back and forward button functionality with the browser. I'm wondering if there is a different approach to this that would retain that functionality.

Comment: I think I figured it out, check jsfiddle.net/ky4La0s1/65/ this will allow me to keep the `location` function, I just need to tweak it a little more.

Comment: @AaronTomason `history.pushState()` is a clever approach. You should post the answer to your question when you get it sorted the way you want.